# how to pass python script variables to a csh script?

Tags: python, shell, csh

I have a python script which asks user to selct one of many options, I would like to use the selected variable in a csh script to proceed further. I am getting undefined variable when I am trying to use the python variable from the shell script.

Here is some reference:

There is a python script choices.py whose output is something like this:

```
Select a Choice:
1) choice1
2) choice2
3) choice3
Choice: 1
Selected Choice: choice1
```

Then in my csh script I am envoking the python script and trying to use the choice variable for subsequent operations. Something like this:

```
python choices.py
echo "$choice"
```

Getting the error:

```
choice: Undefined variable.
```

Is there a way to make the python variable global so that it can be used in other places?

Expected:

```
choice1
```

Getting the error:

```
choice: Undefined variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Csh has no way to know what variables existed in a Python process which has now ceased to exist, just like you have no way to know what C variables exist internally in the C compiler.

A common arrangement is to have your script output a value on standard output, and have the shell capture that:

```
set choice=`python choices.py`
echo "$choice"
```

Of course, if your script already needs standard output for other things (like communicating with the user!) you need a slightly different approach. Perhaps it can write the value to a file, and have the caller read that file?

More tangentially, the C shell has basically been abandoned by all its sane users some 30+ years ago in favor of Bourne-compatible shells. You generally do not want to write scripts using `csh` syntax unless you are writing them strictly for your own private use *and* you have a very odd masochistic fetish. The standard reference for persuading people to switch is [Csh considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) though some of the arguments in that are slightly dubious; the conclusion is still forcefully argued with sane arguments even after you ignore some of the spurious ones. Perhaps see also https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt

Here is the same construct in standard POSIX `sh` syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh
choice=$(python choices.py)
echo "$choice"
```

Comment: Since OP is already using Python, I would recommend to avoid both `csh` and `sh`, and just write everyting in Python instead. Then this question wouldn't even have been asked!

Comment: Yeah, that too.

Comment: I am using someone else's python script in my csh script, I am stuck with csh cuz my job demands it :(

Comment: Probably not in a place where you can change that here and now, but `sh` is guaranteed to exist on basically every system since the 1980s. If you are stuck on something horribly legacy like HP-UP or Solaris, the `sh` implementation may not be very good, but even then it could well be better than Csh.

Comment: That's true, but, I have so many legacy csh scripts that translating them into sh is a difficult exercise in itself.

Comment: @Thomas That depends on what the shell script is doing. Shell script is *very* good at what it was designed for: running other programs. All the other weird shell syntax is due to the need to work around the fact that running other programs is syntactically trivial.